# Call a controller with a parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-controller

Let's imagine I have two Models:

1. A list of users `User`
2. A list of marbles `Marble` which belongs to one `User`

I would like to fetch all the existing marbles with `api/marbles` and only my marbles with `api/user/marbles`. The idea is to avoid a route named like `api/marbles?owned=true`

In my API routes I have this:

```
Route::get('marbles', 'MarbleController@index');
Route::get('user/marbles', 'MarbleController@index(true)');
```

Then in my MarbleController:

```
class MarbleControllerextends Controller
{
    function index($owned = false) {
        return $owned ? Marble::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get() : Marble::all();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `MarbleController@index(true)` doesn't really work because `(true)` will not be accepted by Laravel not populate the optional `$owned` variable.

Is there a way to avoid defining a new method such as `Route::get('user/marbles', 'MarbleController@owned');`

```
    function owned() {
        return $this->index(true);
    }
```

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Indeed, it could work

Comment: @N69S No it doesn't :(

Comment: what version of laravel are you using

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov 8.5

Comment: @N69S `Route::get` only takes 2 arguments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Route::get('marbles/{me?}', 'MarbleController@index'); will work fine.
```

Here `me` is an optional parameter. If you omit it, it will take `false` otherwise `true` as it's value.

Comment: That's probably an anti-pattern, no matter how fine it works (or how the variable is called). I mean, the concept is the problem (as explained above), not necessarily the code.

Comment: The `function index($me=false) {} ` is acceping the perameter. correct? Just access it.